# Regex to substitute a less than (<) with a greater than (>) symbol

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

In Perl, I need to substitute the less than symbol (<) by the greater than symbol (>) by using a regular expression. I tried:

```
s/</>/g;
```

as well as

```
s/</\>/g;
```

which can find the (<) but it doesn't make the substitution.

Any help please. I'm quite new to Perl.

Comment: Add the rest of the code please. That first regex looks correct to me, so it could be another issue.

Comment: Your first regex is working fine for me. You need to provide exact code you are using. It seems that something in your code is issue not in regex.

Comment: The replacement is interpolated. Use `s/</\\>/g`

Comment: This works fine: `perl -E '$_="<";s/</>/g; say'`

Comment: Show your code, probably don't have correct operator, or its working on the default variable $_ .

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I found the problem. Later on my code I had '@Words = split(/>/, $line);' which was eliminating the (>). I fixed it. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to substitute just one character with another one character, try with **`tr///`**:

```
$text =~ tr/</>/;
```

Comment: Transliterate is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

`s/</>/g` is actually correct.

```
$ perl -E'
    my $s = "abc<def<ghi";
    $s =~ s/</>/g;
    say $s;
'
abc>def>ghi
```

`tr/</>/` would be faster, though.

```
$ perl -E'
    my $s = "abc<def<ghi";
    $s =~ tr/</>/;
    say $s;
'
abc>def>ghi
```